# Java "Broken Pipe" Error (using Unirest http wrapper)

Tags: java, http, post, unirest, mashape

I'm using the unirest http wrapper (http://unirest.io/java.html) in a Java application to send http post requests. Unfortunately I keep getting a "broken pipe" error:

```
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:145)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)
```

The code I'm using to call it is as follows:

```
public static int doHTTPPostWithAdditionalHeaders(String data, String url, HashMap<String, String> additionalHeaders) {

    try {
        Unirest.setTimeouts(10000, 10000);
        HttpResponse<String> jsonResponse = Unirest.post(url)
                .headers(additionalHeaders)
                .body(data)
                .asString();

        return jsonResponse.getStatus();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("doHTTPPostWithAdditionalHeaders failed: "+e.toString());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works most of the time but seems to fail when I'm hammering it with lots of requests. Have any of you got any ideas how I might solve this, or perhaps could you recommend a more robust solution? This post operation is mission critical to my application.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it was a simple case of the data I was posting being too large for the allocated timeouts.

**Old**

```
Unirest.setTimeouts(10000, 10000);
```

**New**

```
Unirest.setTimeouts(10000, 30000);
```